# What's the fastest stride-3 gather instruction sequence?

Tags: c++, x86, vectorization, avx2

### The question:

What is the most efficient sequence to generate a stride-3 gather of 32-bit elements from memory?
If the memory is arranged as:

```
MEM = R0 G0 B0 R1 G1 B1 R2 G2 B2 R3 G3 B3 ...
```

We want to obtain three YMM registers where:

```
YMM0 = R0 R1 R2 R3 R4 R5 R6 R7
YMM1 = G0 G1 G2 G3 G4 G5 G6 G7
YMM2 = B0 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7
```

### Motivation and discussion

The scalar C code is something like

```
template <typename T>
T Process(const T* Input) {
  T Result = 0;
  for (int i=0; i < 4096; ++i) {
    T R = Input[3*i];
    T G = Input[3*i+1];
    T B = Input[3*i+2];
    Result += some_parallelizable_algorithm<T>(R, G, B);  
  }
  return Result;
}
```

Let's say that *some_parallelizable_algorithm* was written in intrinsics and was tuned to the fastest possible implementation possible:

```
template <typename T>
__m256i some_parallelizable_algorithm(__m256i R, __m256i G, __m256i B);
```

So the vector implementation for T=int32_t can be something like:

```
    template <>
    int32_t Process<int32_t>(const int32_t* Input) {
     __m256i Step = _mm256_set_epi32(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
     __m256i Result = _mm256_setzero_si256(); 
     for (int i=0; i < 4096; i+=8) {
       // R = R0 R1 R2 R3 R4 R5 R6 R7
       __m256i R = _mm256_i32gather_epi32 (Input+3*i, Step, 3);
       // G = G0 G1 G2 G3 G4 G5 G6 G7
       __m256i G = _mm256_i32gather_epi32 (Input+3*i+1, Step, 3);
       // B = B0 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7
       __m256i B = _mm256_i32gather_epi32 (Input+3*i+2, Step, 3);
       Result = _mm256_add_epi32 (Result, 
                                  some_parallelizable_algorithm<int32_t>(R, G, B));
     }
   // Here should be the less interesting part:
   // Perform a reduction on Result and return the result
}
```

First, this can be done because there are gather instructions for 32-bit elements, but there are none for 16-bit elements or 8-bit elements.
Second, and more importantly, the gather instruction above should be entirely avoided for performance reasons. It is probably more efficient to use contiguous wide loads and shuffle the loaded values to obtain the R, G and B vectors.

```
    template <>
    int32_t Process<int32_t>(const int32_t* Input) {
     __m256i Result = _mm256_setzero_si256(); 
     for (int i=0; i < 4096; i+=3) {
       __m256i Ld0 = _mm256_lddqu_si256((__m256i*)Input+3*i));
       __m256i Ld1 = _mm256_lddqu_si256((__m256i*)Input+3*i+1));
       __m256i Ld2 = _mm256_lddqu_si256((__m256i*)Input+3*i+2));
       __m256i R = ???
       __m256i G = ???
       __m256i B = ???
       Result = _mm256_add_epi32 (Result, 
                                  some_parallelizable_algorithm<int32_t>(R, G, B));
     }
   // Here should be the less interesting part:
   // Perform a reduction on Result and return the result
}
```

It seems that for power-2 strides (2, 4, ...) there are known methods using UNKPCKL/UNKPCKH, but for stride-3 accesses i could not find any references.

I am interested in solving this for T=int32_t, T=int16_t and T=int8_t, but to remain focused let's only discuss the first case.

Comment: *It is probably more efficient to use contiguous wide loads and shuffle*.  Yes, definitely, but you're right that it's non-obvious how to do this well.  >.<  Taking advantage of 2-input shuffles like shufps and punpckl/h seem like a good idea, but there's probably going to have to be some `pshufb` and `por` as well.  Maybe we can mask and use `packuswb` somehow, and do something with a vector that has a mix of R, G, and B?  Probably not, since masking inputs to defeat saturation is expensive, and merging probably requires `vpblendvb` (expensive compared to `vpblendd`)

Comment: Maybe `pshufb` to set up two inputs for `packuswb` (since `pshufb` zeros elements where the high bit of the control vector is set), and merge in the 3rd with another `pshufb` + `por`?

Comment: In some cases, Intel compiler might be able to do it for you if auto-vectorization is possible - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1182515/Vectorization-Opportunities-for-Improved-Perform

Comment: @PeterCordes There's a general approach to these "odd-sized" interleaves that maintains the `O(N*log(SIMD-width))` instruction count (it's `O(N * SIMD-width)` if you use scalar instructions). As I've needed them as high as stride-19. But I don't have it in front of me atm as it's quite complicated.

Comment: @Mysticial Would appreciate any references that could help.

Comment: @zr. They don't exist. It's something I derived a couple years ago when I faced the same problem and I haven't published it anywhere. So unless someone else reinvented it (or I reinvented from if they came first), you won't find the reference. I'll post the solution to the 3-stride when I get home from work since I don't have access to it here.

Comment: My earlier comments were for the T=int8_t version of the problem.  I didn't even notice that T=int32_t was part of the question; I just saw the pixel-components use-case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This article from Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/3d-vector-normalization-using-256-bit-intel-advanced-vector-extensions-intel-avx) describes how to do exactly the 3x8 case that you want.

That article covers the `float` case. If you want `int32`, you'll need to cast the outputs since there's no integer version of `_mm256_shuffle_ps()`.

[image]

Copying their solution verbatim:

```
float *p;  // address of first vector
__m128 *m = (__m128*) p;
__m256 m03;
__m256 m14; 
__m256 m25; 
m03  = _mm256_castps128_ps256(m[0]); // load lower halves
m14  = _mm256_castps128_ps256(m[1]);
m25  = _mm256_castps128_ps256(m[2]);
m03  = _mm256_insertf128_ps(m03 ,m[3],1);  // load upper halves
m14  = _mm256_insertf128_ps(m14 ,m[4],1);
m25  = _mm256_insertf128_ps(m25 ,m[5],1);

__m256 xy = _mm256_shuffle_ps(m14, m25, _MM_SHUFFLE( 2,1,3,2)); // upper x's and y's 
__m256 yz = _mm256_shuffle_ps(m03, m14, _MM_SHUFFLE( 1,0,2,1)); // lower y's and z's
__m256 x  = _mm256_shuffle_ps(m03, xy , _MM_SHUFFLE( 2,0,3,0)); 
__m256 y  = _mm256_shuffle_ps(yz , xy , _MM_SHUFFLE( 3,1,2,0)); 
__m256 z  = _mm256_shuffle_ps(yz , m25, _MM_SHUFFLE( 3,0,3,1));
```

So this is 11 instructions. (6 loads, 5 shuffles)

---

In the general case, it's possible to do an `S x W` transpose in `O(S*log(W))` instructions. Where:

- `S` is the stride
- `W` is the SIMD width

Assuming the existence of 2-vector permutes and half-vector insert-loads, then the formula becomes:

```
(S x W load-permute)  <=  S * (lg(W) + 1) instructions
```

Ignoring reg-reg moves. For degenerate cases like the `3 x 4`, it may be possible to do better.

Here's the `3 x 16` load-transpose with AVX512: (6 loads, 3 shuffles, 6 blends)

```
FORCE_INLINE void transpose_f32_16x3_forward_AVX512(
    const float T[48],
    __m512& r0, __m512& r1, __m512& r2
){
    __m512 a0, a1, a2;

    //   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
    //  16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
    //  32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47

    a0 = _mm512_castps256_ps512(_mm256_loadu_ps(T +  0));
    a1 = _mm512_castps256_ps512(_mm256_loadu_ps(T +  8));
    a2 = _mm512_castps256_ps512(_mm256_loadu_ps(T + 16));
    a0 = _mm512_insertf32x8(a0, ((const __m256*)T)[3], 1);
    a1 = _mm512_insertf32x8(a1, ((const __m256*)T)[4], 1);
    a2 = _mm512_insertf32x8(a2, ((const __m256*)T)[5], 1);

    //   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
    //   8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
    //  16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47

    r0 = _mm512_mask_blend_ps(0xf0f0, a0, a1);
    r1 = _mm512_permutex2var_ps(a0, _mm512_setr_epi32(  4,  5,  6,  7, 16, 17, 18, 19, 12, 13, 14, 15, 24, 25, 26, 27), a2);
    r2 = _mm512_mask_blend_ps(0xf0f0, a1, a2);

    //   0  1  2  3 12 13 14 15 24 25 26 27 36 37 38 39
    //   4  5  6  7 16 17 18 19 28 29 30 31 40 41 42 43
    //   8  9 10 11 20 21 22 23 32 33 34 35 44 45 46 47

    a0 = _mm512_mask_blend_ps(0xcccc, r0, r1);
    a1 = _mm512_shuffle_ps(r0, r2, 78);
    a2 = _mm512_mask_blend_ps(0xcccc, r1, r2);

    //   0  1  6  7 12 13 18 19 24 25 30 31 36 37 42 43
    //   2  3  8  9 14 15 20 21 26 27 32 33 38 39 44 45
    //   4  5 10 11 16 17 22 23 28 29 34 35 40 41 46 47

    r0 = _mm512_mask_blend_ps(0xaaaa, a0, a1);
    r1 = _mm512_permutex2var_ps(a0, _mm512_setr_epi32(  1,  16,  3, 18,  5, 20,  7, 22,  9, 24, 11, 26, 13, 28, 15, 30), a2);
    r2 = _mm512_mask_blend_ps(0xaaaa, a1, a2);

    //   0  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36 39 42 45
    //   1  4  7 10 13 16 19 22 25 28 31 34 37 40 43 46
    //   2  5  8 11 14 17 20 23 26 29 32 35 38 41 44 47
}
```

The inverse `3 x 16` transpose-store will be left as an exercise to the reader.

The pattern is not at all trivial to see since the `S = 3` is somewhat degenerate. But if you can see the pattern, you'll be able to generalize this to any odd integer `S` as well as any power-of-two `W`.

Comment: Note that `vinsertf128 y,y,m,imm8` is a 2-uop load+blend instruction on Intel/AMD CPUs.  So I might say the cost is "3 loads, 3 load+blends, 5 shuffles".  (On Sandybridge, `vinsertf128` from a memory source needs port5, but on HSW/SKL and Ryzen the ALU uop runs on any vector ALU port.)

Comment: This only answers the `int32_t` part of question, right?  It looks like significantly more work for narrower elements, because there isn't a smaller-element version of `shufps`.  Like maybe `pshufb` within inputs to group the elements together before feeding to `shufps`?

Comment: @PeterCordes You can also trade away the 3 half-vector loads + 3 half-vector inserts for 3 full-vector loads + 3 permutes. It just isn't a good trade-off on current CPUs since you're adding port5 pressure.

Comment: @PeterCordes Extending to any granularity (including byte) is possible as long as you provide a way to do the appropriate permutes. At the smaller granularities, you'll notice that the 2-vector permutes don't actually cross any lanes. So they can be emulated with shifts + blend-masking - thereby taking even more pressure off of port5. My `3 x 16` on AVX512 example has more blends than shuffles, so it probably isn't even port5 bound. The generic `S x W` algorithm requires 9 x 2-vector shuffles for the `3 x 16` case. It just happens that 6 of those shuffles reduce to blends.

Comment: @PeterCordes Hmm... The 3 x 16 AVX512 case is small enough to brute-force it using 2-vector permutes. 3 x 512-bit loads and 6 x `_mm512_permutex2var_ps()`. There are 3 outputs and each of them have only 3 inputs. 2 permutes will let you pull anything you want from 3 vectors. So `3 x 2 = 6` permutes. If I get the time tonight, I might throw together that solution. The one in my solution here is just a direct deviation from the generic `S x W` approach. That generic approach is really only useful for when `S >= 5`.

Answer (score 3):

**The 8-bit integer case.**

As already mentioned in the comments above, two input shuffle instructions, such as `vshufps`, don't 
exist for 8-bit granularity. Hence, the 8-bit solution differs a bit from the 32-bit solution. Two different solutions are described below.

---

A straightforward approach is to group the 8-bit integers 'color by color (R G B)' with 6 `vpblendvb`-s, followed 
by a `vpshufb` permutation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>
/*  gcc -O3 -Wall -m64 -march=broadwell stride_3.c   */
int __attribute__ ((noinline)) print_vec_char(__m256i x);

int main() {

    char *m;
    int i;
    __m256i blnd1 = _mm256_set_epi8(0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,     0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0);
    __m256i blnd2 = _mm256_set_epi8(0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,     0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0);
    __m256i p0    = _mm256_set_epi8(13,10,7,4,1, 14,11,8,5,2, 15,12,9,6,3,0,    13,10,7,4,1, 14,11,8,5,2, 15,12,9,6,3,0);
    __m256i p1    = _mm256_set_epi8(14,11,8,5,2, 15,12,9,6,3,0, 13,10,7,4,1,    14,11,8,5,2, 15,12,9,6,3,0, 13,10,7,4,1);
    __m256i p2    = _mm256_set_epi8(15,12,9,6,3,0, 13,10,7,4,1, 14,11,8,5,2,    15,12,9,6,3,0, 13,10,7,4,1, 14,11,8,5,2);
            m     = _mm_malloc(96,32);
    for(i = 0; i < 96; i++) m[i] = i;

//        printf("m_lo  ");print_vec_char(_mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)&m[0]));printf("m_mid ");print_vec_char(_mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)&m[32]));printf("m_hi  ");print_vec_char(_mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)&m[64]));printf("\n");
//        m_lo   31  30  29  28 |  27  26  25  24 |  23  22  21  20 |  19  18  17  16 ||  15  14  13  12 |  11  10   9   8 |   7   6   5   4 |   3   2   1   0 
//        m_mid  63  62  61  60 |  59  58  57  56 |  55  54  53  52 |  51  50  49  48 ||  47  46  45  44 |  43  42  41  40 |  39  38  37  36 |  35  34  33  32 
//        m_hi   95  94  93  92 |  91  90  89  88 |  87  86  85  84 |  83  82  81  80 ||  79  78  77  76 |  75  74  73  72 |  71  70  69  68 |  67  66  65  64 

    __m256i t0 = _mm256_castsi128_si256(_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&m[0]));
    __m256i t1 = _mm256_castsi128_si256(_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&m[16]));
    __m256i t2 = _mm256_castsi128_si256(_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&m[32]));

            t0 = _mm256_inserti128_si256(t0,_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&m[48]),1);
            t1 = _mm256_inserti128_si256(t1,_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&m[64]),1);
            t2 = _mm256_inserti128_si256(t2,_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&m[80]),1);

//        printf("t0  ");print_vec_char(t0);printf("t1  ");print_vec_char(t1);printf("t2  ");print_vec_char(t2);printf("\n");
//        t0   63  62  61  60 |  59  58  57  56 |  55  54  53  52 |  51  50  49  48 ||  15  14  13  12 |  11  10   9   8 |   7   6   5   4 |   3   2   1   0 
//        t1   79  78  77  76 |  75  74  73  72 |  71  70  69  68 |  67  66  65  64 ||  31  30  29  28 |  27  26  25  24 |  23  22  21  20 |  19  18  17  16 
//        t2   95  94  93  92 |  91  90  89  88 |  87  86  85  84 |  83  82  81  80 ||  47  46  45  44 |  43  42  41  40 |  39  38  37  36 |  35  34  33  32 

    __m256i u0 = _mm256_blendv_epi8( _mm256_blendv_epi8(t0,t1,blnd2), t2,blnd1);
    __m256i u1 = _mm256_blendv_epi8( _mm256_blendv_epi8(t1,t2,blnd2), t0,blnd1);
    __m256i u2 = _mm256_blendv_epi8( _mm256_blendv_epi8(t2,t0,blnd2), t1,blnd1);

//        printf("u0  ");print_vec_char(u0);printf("u1  ");print_vec_char(u1);printf("u2  ");print_vec_char(u2);printf("\n");
//        u0   63  78  93  60 |  75  90  57  72 |  87  54  69  84 |  51  66  81  48 ||  15  30  45  12 |  27  42   9  24 |  39   6  21  36 |   3  18  33   0 
//        u1   79  94  61  76 |  91  58  73  88 |  55  70  85  52 |  67  82  49  64 ||  31  46  13  28 |  43  10  25  40 |   7  22  37   4 |  19  34   1  16 
//        u2   95  62  77  92 |  59  74  89  56 |  71  86  53  68 |  83  50  65  80 ||  47  14  29  44 |  11  26  41   8 |  23  38   5  20 |  35   2  17  32 

            t0 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(u0,p0);
            t1 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(u1,p1);
            t2 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(u2,p2);

          printf("t0  ");print_vec_char(t0);printf("t1  ");print_vec_char(t1);printf("t2  ");print_vec_char(t2);printf("\n");
//        t0   93  90  87  84 |  81  78  75  72 |  69  66  63  60 |  57  54  51  48 ||  45  42  39  36 |  33  30  27  24 |  21  18  15  12 |   9   6   3   0 
//        t1   94  91  88  85 |  82  79  76  73 |  70  67  64  61 |  58  55  52  49 ||  46  43  40  37 |  34  31  28  25 |  22  19  16  13 |  10   7   4   1 
//        t2   95  92  89  86 |  83  80  77  74 |  71  68  65  62 |  59  56  53  50 ||  47  44  41  38 |  35  32  29  26 |  23  20  17  14 |  11   8   5   2 

    return 0;
}



int __attribute__ ((noinline)) print_vec_char(__m256i x){
    char v[32];
    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i *)v,x);
    printf("%3hhi %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi | %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi | %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi | %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi || ",
           v[31],v[30],v[29],v[28],v[27],v[26],v[25],v[24],v[23],v[22],v[21],v[20],v[19],v[18],v[17],v[16]);
    printf("%3hhi %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi | %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi | %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi | %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi \n",
           v[15],v[14],v[13],v[12],v[11],v[10],v[9],v[8],v[7],v[6],v[5],v[4],v[3],v[2],v[1],v[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Instruction summary:

```
    3 vmovdqu
    3 vinserti128-load
    6 vpblendvb   
    3 vpshufb
```

Unfortunately, the `vpblendvb` instruction is often relatively slow:
on Intel Skylake `vpblendvb` has a throughput of one per cycle and
on AMD Ryzen and Intel Haswell the throughput is only one per two cylcles.
Skylake-X has a fast byte blend `vpblendmb`(throughput three per cycle (256-bit) ), although on Skylake-X one might be more 
interested in a solution that works with 512-bit vectors instead of 256-bit.

---

An alternative is to combine `vpshufb` with `vshufps`, as suggested in @Peter Cordes' comments above.
In the code below the data is loaded as 12-byte chunks. Altogether more instructions are needed than in the first solution.
Nevertheless, the performance of this second solution is probably better than the first solution, depending on the surrounding code
and the micro architecture.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>
/*  gcc -O3 -Wall -m64 -march=broadwell stride_3.c   */
int __attribute__ ((noinline)) print_vec_char(__m256i x);

inline __m256i _mm256_shufps_epi32(__m256i a,__m256i b,int imm){return _mm256_castps_si256(_mm256_shuffle_ps(_mm256_castsi256_ps(a),_mm256_castsi256_ps(b),imm));}

int main() {

    char *m;
    int i;
    __m256i p0    = _mm256_set_epi8(-1,-1,-1,-1, 11,8,5,2, 10,7,4,1, 9,6,3,0,     -1,-1,-1,-1, 11,8,5,2, 10,7,4,1, 9,6,3,0);
    __m256i p1    = _mm256_set_epi8(11,8,5,2, 10,7,4,1, 9,6,3,0, -1,-1,-1,-1,     11,8,5,2, 10,7,4,1, 9,6,3,0, -1,-1,-1,-1);
    __m256i p2    = _mm256_set_epi8(10,7,4,1, 9,6,3,0, -1,-1,-1,-1, 11,8,5,2,     10,7,4,1, 9,6,3,0,-1, -1,-1,-1, 11,8,5,2);
    __m256i p3    = _mm256_set_epi8(9,6,3,0, -1,-1,-1,-1, 11,8,5,2, 10,7,4,1,     9,6,3,0, -1,-1,-1,-1, 11,8,5,2, 10,7,4,1);

            m     = _mm_malloc(96+4,32);   /* 4 extra dummy bytes to avoid errors with _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&m[84]) . Otherwise use maskload instead of standard load */
    for(i = 0; i < 96; i++) m[i] = i;

//        printf("m_lo  ");print_vec_char(_mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)&m[0]));printf("m_mid ");print_vec_char(_mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)&m[32]));printf("m_hi  ");print_vec_char(_mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)&m[64]));printf("\n");
//        m_lo   31  30  29  28 |  27  26  25  24 |  23  22  21  20 |  19  18  17  16 ||  15  14  13  12 |  11  10   9   8 |   7   6   5   4 |   3   2   1   0 
//        m_mid  63  62  61  60 |  59  58  57  56 |  55  54  53  52 |  51  50  49  48 ||  47  46  45  44 |  43  42  41  40 |  39  38  37  36 |  35  34  33  32 
//        m_hi   95  94  93  92 |  91  90  89  88 |  87  86  85  84 |  83  82  81  80 ||  79  78  77  76 |  75  74  73  72 |  71  70  69  68 |  67  66  65  64 

    __m256i t0 = _mm256_castsi128_si256(_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&m[0]));
    __m256i t1 = _mm256_castsi128_si256(_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&m[12]));
    __m256i t2 = _mm256_castsi128_si256(_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&m[24]));
    __m256i t3 = _mm256_castsi128_si256(_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&m[36]));

            t0 = _mm256_inserti128_si256(t0,_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&m[48]),1);
            t1 = _mm256_inserti128_si256(t1,_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&m[60]),1);
            t2 = _mm256_inserti128_si256(t2,_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&m[72]),1);
            t3 = _mm256_inserti128_si256(t3,_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&m[84]),1);   /* Use a masked load (_mm_maskload_epi32) here if m[99] is not a valid address */

//        printf("t0  ");print_vec_char(t0);printf("t1  ");print_vec_char(t1);printf("t2  ");print_vec_char(t2);printf("t3  ");print_vec_char(t3);printf("\n");
//        t0   63  62  61  60 |  59  58  57  56 |  55  54  53  52 |  51  50  49  48 ||  15  14  13  12 |  11  10   9   8 |   7   6   5   4 |   3   2   1   0 
//        t1   75  74  73  72 |  71  70  69  68 |  67  66  65  64 |  63  62  61  60 ||  27  26  25  24 |  23  22  21  20 |  19  18  17  16 |  15  14  13  12 
//        t2   87  86  85  84 |  83  82  81  80 |  79  78  77  76 |  75  74  73  72 ||  39  38  37  36 |  35  34  33  32 |  31  30  29  28 |  27  26  25  24 
//        t3    0   0   0   0 |  95  94  93  92 |  91  90  89  88 |  87  86  85  84 ||  51  50  49  48 |  47  46  45  44 |  43  42  41  40 |  39  38  37  36 

            t0 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(t0,p0);
            t1 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(t1,p1);
            t2 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(t2,p2);
            t3 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(t3,p3);

//        printf("t0  ");print_vec_char(t0);printf("t1  ");print_vec_char(t1);printf("t2  ");print_vec_char(t2);printf("t3  ");print_vec_char(t3);printf("\n");
//        t0    0   0   0   0 |  59  56  53  50 |  58  55  52  49 |  57  54  51  48 ||   0   0   0   0 |  11   8   5   2 |  10   7   4   1 |   9   6   3   0 
//        t1   71  68  65  62 |  70  67  64  61 |  69  66  63  60 |   0   0   0   0 ||  23  20  17  14 |  22  19  16  13 |  21  18  15  12 |   0   0   0   0 
//        t2   82  79  76  73 |  81  78  75  72 |   0   0   0   0 |  83  80  77  74 ||  34  31  28  25 |  33  30  27  24 |   0   0   0   0 |  35  32  29  26 
//        t3   93  90  87  84 |   0   0   0   0 |  95  92  89  86 |  94  91  88  85 ||  45  42  39  36 |   0   0   0   0 |  47  44  41  38 |  46  43  40  37 

    __m256i u0 = _mm256_blend_epi32(t0,t1,0b10101010);
    __m256i u1 = _mm256_blend_epi32(t2,t3,0b10101010);
    __m256i u2 = _mm256_blend_epi32(t0,t1,0b01010101);
    __m256i u3 = _mm256_blend_epi32(t2,t3,0b01010101);

//        printf("u0  ");print_vec_char(u0);printf("u1  ");print_vec_char(u1);printf("u2  ");print_vec_char(u2);printf("u3  ");print_vec_char(u3);printf("\n");
//        u0   71  68  65  62 |  59  56  53  50 |  69  66  63  60 |  57  54  51  48 ||  23  20  17  14 |  11   8   5   2 |  21  18  15  12 |   9   6   3   0 
//        u1   93  90  87  84 |  81  78  75  72 |  95  92  89  86 |  83  80  77  74 ||  45  42  39  36 |  33  30  27  24 |  47  44  41  38 |  35  32  29  26 
//        u2    0   0   0   0 |  70  67  64  61 |  58  55  52  49 |   0   0   0   0 ||   0   0   0   0 |  22  19  16  13 |  10   7   4   1 |   0   0   0   0 
//        u3   82  79  76  73 |   0   0   0   0 |   0   0   0   0 |  94  91  88  85 ||  34  31  28  25 |   0   0   0   0 |   0   0   0   0 |  46  43  40  37 

            t0 = _mm256_blend_epi32(u0,u1,0b11001100);
            t1 = _mm256_shufps_epi32(u2,u3,0b00111001);
            t2 = _mm256_shufps_epi32(u0,u1,0b01001110);

        printf("t0  ");print_vec_char(t0);printf("t1  ");print_vec_char(t1);printf("t2  ");print_vec_char(t2);printf("\n");
//        t0   93  90  87  84 |  81  78  75  72 |  69  66  63  60 |  57  54  51  48 ||  45  42  39  36 |  33  30  27  24 |  21  18  15  12 |   9   6   3   0 
//        t1   94  91  88  85 |  82  79  76  73 |  70  67  64  61 |  58  55  52  49 ||  46  43  40  37 |  34  31  28  25 |  22  19  16  13 |  10   7   4   1 
//        t2   95  92  89  86 |  83  80  77  74 |  71  68  65  62 |  59  56  53  50 ||  47  44  41  38 |  35  32  29  26 |  23  20  17  14 |  11   8   5   2 

    return 0;
}



int __attribute__ ((noinline)) print_vec_char(__m256i x){
    char v[32];
    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i *)v,x);
    printf("%3hhi %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi | %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi | %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi | %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi || ",
           v[31],v[30],v[29],v[28],v[27],v[26],v[25],v[24],v[23],v[22],v[21],v[20],v[19],v[18],v[17],v[16]);
    printf("%3hhi %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi | %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi | %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi | %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi %3hhi \n",
           v[15],v[14],v[13],v[12],v[11],v[10],v[9],v[8],v[7],v[6],v[5],v[4],v[3],v[2],v[1],v[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Instruction summary:

```
    4 vmovdqu
    4 vinserti128-load
    4 vpshufb
    5 vpblendd    (vpblendd is much faster than vpblendvb on most cpu architectures)
    2 vshufps
```

It is easy to adapt the ideas of these methods to the 16-bit case.

Comment: Cool, interesting to see how my idea panned out with a full implementation :)  (And BTW, `vpblendvb` on Haswell is extra-bad here because it's 2 uops for port 5, so it competes directly with `vpshufb`.  Agner says it's 2 uops for p015 on SKL, but strangely still only 1 per clock.)  Anyway, on Haswell, the shufps version has 6 shuffle-port uops vs. 15 for the vblendvb version.  Using unaligned loads to replace / simplify shuffles is definitely a useful trick.

Comment: @PeterCordes I did a few simple tests, with irrelevant surrounding code, but even on Skylake the `vpblendvb` version seems to be slower than the `vpshufb + vshufps` version. Nevertheless, the byte blending idea might be of interest if ever a fast lane crossing `_mm512_permutexvar_epi8(idx, a)` comes available with the `AVX512VBMI` instruction set.